# Error while loading a chart Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

we have gone through the other entries related to the issue. But it doesn't seem to fix my issue. Im trying to load a page and there is a js function which loads a graph.when trying to access the application deployed locally,it works fine without any errors. But when trying to access the link (page of the same application deployed in the server) , We are gettint the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

```
function show_vis(tower, cluster, product,region,all_application, flag) 
{
document.getElementById('heat-chart').innerHTML='';
var appList = [];
var app_corr = [];
var indexarr = new Array();
    // second issue fixed....
    tower   = encodeURIComponent(tower);    
    cluster = encodeURIComponent(cluster);
    product     = encodeURIComponent(product);
    region      = encodeURIComponent(region);
    flag        = encodeURIComponent(flag);

$.get("Dashboard_Core_Analysis.jsp?tower=" + tower
        + "&cluster=" + cluster +"&region="+region+ "&product=" + product + "&default=" +flag, function(data, status) {
    appList=data.trim().split('\r\n');
    if(appList.length != 1 ){
        for(var i = 1 ; i < all_application.length ; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0 ; j < appList.length ; j++)
            {

                **if (all_application[i][1].toLowerCase() == appList[j].toLowerCase())**
                {
                    indexarr.push(all_application[i][0]);
                    app_corr.push(all_application[i][1]);
                }
            }
        }
        buildHeatMap(app_corr, indexarr, flag);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('heat-chart').innerHTML='<div style="Margin-top:50px; text-align:center;">No Data to Display</div>';
        document.getElementById('tag-cloud').innerHTML='';
        document.getElementById('area-chart1').innerHTML='';
        document.getElementById('area-chart2').innerHTML='';
    }

});
```

}
I have even debugged the code and kept an alert to check if the values are being populated for all_application & appList. The values are getting populated fine. Below are the values

all_application values

```
index,application_name,
1,Friday Daily Jobs WK1,
2,Monday Additional Jobs,
3,Monday Daily Jobs,
4,Non Daily Jobs,
5,NonBATCHNDC Daily Jobs,
6,Others,
7,Tue-Fri Daily,
```

appList values

```
Monday Daily Jobs,Non Daily Jobs,Tue-Fri Daily,Friday Daily Jobs WK1,Monday Additional Jobs,NonBATCHNDC Daily Jobs,Others
```

Above is the function that is invoked and it loads a graph.In the above method,when the highlighted line is getting invoked, the application through an uncaught TypeError.

The same code works fine when the application is deployed locally in a tomcat server. Im not sure what is missing. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: what is `all_application` and `appList`?

Comment: Log both those values and see what is happening

Comment: Most probably it is failing when `all_application[i][1]` is undefined. (i.e., when there are empty lines in the data read from the api)

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, but that is not the case, the all_application has values and i have updated my question with the list which i got at runtime for app_application

Comment: is all_application a bidimensional array? it doesn't look like so. Is it possible that it's an object and not an array? can you show us the output of a console.log(all_application); (the printed output is not enough) ?

Comment: Hi Valepu, thanks a lot.  the all_application is a bidimensional array. I have put console.log(all_application) and checked the output.In the console, the size of the array is displayed as 9. Where as there are only 8 elements in the csv file.I guess when its trying to enter the loop/convert the null object to lower case, the application is throwing that Uncaught Type error.

Comment: well yes, if you try to call a function on a null value it will give you an error. I think the issue is that there are empty lines at the end of the csv file, try to delete them

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get rid of the same. I have opened the file and tried to delete the empty spaces but that doesnt seem to work.  On further analysis I found the issue is with the data retrieved from the csv file. I have posted a query for the same. The link for it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006154/reading-a-csv-file-using-ajax.

Comment: i know it sounds like an obvious thing to say but i'm just making sure at this point. You don't just need to delete the empty spaces but also the newlines. If go to the end of the file and your caret is at the start of a new line, delete it using backspace so that the caret position is at the end of a line with text and can't go further down

Comment: Pheww.. Finally it worked.I opened the csv file in notepad++ and was able to view empty line at the end of the file which was causing the problem. The issue is fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the question comments the issue was that data is taken from a csv file, this file had empty spaces and an empty line at the end which was causing the array to add an empty value.

Some libraries or hand-made code that extract data from a csv don't check for empty lines and this may causes issues like the one seen in this question so you must make sure to either trim your csv file or use code that checks for empty lines